# (My)SQL: Proclaimed load difference between SMALLINT(4) en INT(4) real?

Tags: mysql, sql

According to [this (Dutch) webpage](http://www.webmasterstart.nl/php/datatypes-in-mysql.html), one should use `SMALLINT` if the expected number will not exceed 9999 (4 digits), because `INT` would reserve too much system resources (free interpretation). But does that still count if the digits are limited, as in `SMALLINT(4)` and `INT(4)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the upper limit of a `SMALLINT` is not 9999 but 32767 - numbers are not stored in decimal, so the number of digits in the decimal representation of a number is irrelevant. So while it is the correct type to use for numbers not exceeding 9999, it is also the correct type for numbers not exceeding 19999, for instance.

Secondly, the storage required for each type is given on [the MySQL manual page describing the types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html). Larger types will certainly reserve *more* resources; whether they reserve *too much* is another matter.

The `INT(4)` syntax you referred to is a MySQL-specific feature discussed separately in the manual under [Numeric Type Attributes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/numeric-type-attributes.html). According to that page, it represents a "display width", in digits, constraining the *minimum* width when displaying values. It specifically states that "The display width does not constrain the range of values that can be stored in the column." so the storage allocated could not be adjusted downwards based on that hint.

Comment: I know that it runs up to 32767, but it would be much smarter to use MEDIUMINT if the numbers are expected to have 5 digits. Furthermore, together with the pages you linked, an utterly clear and concise answer. Thanks!

Comment: @FrankConijn The point is you may well have some natural limit that's not a number of digits - if you know that your values will never exceed 20000, thinking "that's 5 digits, so I'll use a MEDIUMINT" would be a mistake.

Comment: I know, but I like the KISS principle, for several reasons.

Comment: @FrankConijn I would agree for higher limits like "4 bytes signed has a limit of about 2 billion", but for smaller widths, you're capping at 9999 something which can hold a number 3 times that size, because you're stuck thinking in decimal multiples.

Answer (score 1):

Before answer your question Frank, let's take a look on the size of types:

```
tinyint: 1 byte, -128 to +127 / 0 to 255 (unsigned)
smallint: 2 bytes, -32,768 to +32,767 / 0 to 65,535 (unsigned)
mediumint: 3 bytes, -8,388,608 to 8,388,607 / 0 to 16,777,215 (unsigned)
int/integer: 4 bytes, -2,147,483,648 to +2,147,483,647 / 0 to 4,294,967,295 (unsigned)
bigint: 8 bytes, -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / 0 to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 (unsigned)
```

Every time you use INT(4), INT(3), INT(1) the number in the brackets is not about the storage, but how many you want to display/output. It is not related with the storage factor. Which means, 183542 is gonna still be kept as it is in a INT(2) field.